# Java program to perform arithmetic on fractions, using two classes

Tags: java, oop

So I am a beginner at programming and I'm having trouble with this assignment for my programming class. The assignment is to create a Java program using two classes that can perform arithmetic on fractions. I think my main issue is with the object-oriented concepts I need to use for this project like classes and objects. I'm still pretty confused about how constructors, accessors, mutators etc work.

The first class, Fraction.java, contains the method definitions for all the arithmetic operations as well as methods to find the greatest common denominator, to reduce the fractions, and to print the results. I have created the printFraction, reduceFraction, gcd, and addFraction methods but I have yet to try the subtract, multiply, or divide.

The second class, TestFraction.java, is designed to implement the Fraction class and test its capabilities. I have written some code in this class to test the Fraction class while I'm still working and the methods I have (print, reduce, and gcd) seem to work besides the addFraction one. It looks like it prints a memory address or something instead of the fraction I'm looking for. I have an idea why but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's my code so far. Like I said, I'm a beginner and I'm sure it's not very good but I'm mostly worried with finishing and getting the program to work. If you have any advice, please try to make it easy for me to understand. Here's a sample output: [sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0JbS.png)

Fraction.java:

```
public class Fraction {
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    //no-arg constructor
    Fraction() {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    //constructor
    Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    //accessor for numerator
    int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    //mutator for numerator
    void setNumerator(int num) {
        numerator = num;
    }

    //accessor for denominator
    int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    //mutator for denominator
    void setDenominator(int denom) {
        denominator = denom;
    }

    //printFraction method concatenates the numerator and denominator with a "/" string between them
    static void printFraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        System.out.print(numerator + "/" + denominator);
    }

    //reduceFraction method uses the gcd method to print a reduced version of the fraction given
    public static void reduceFraction(int numerator, int denominator) {
        int smaller;
        if (numerator < denominator) {
            smaller = numerator;
        }
        else {
            smaller = denominator;
        }
        for (int i = smaller; i > 0; --i) {
            if (numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0) {
                System.out.print("Reduced form: " + (numerator/gcd(numerator, denominator)) + "/" + (denominator/gcd(numerator, denominator)));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //recursive method that calls itself until it reduces completely to the gcd
    public static int gcd(int numerator, int denominator) {
        if (numerator % denominator == 0) {
            return denominator;
        }
        return gcd(denominator, numerator % denominator);
    }

    public static Fraction addFraction(Fraction a, Fraction b) {
        return new Fraction((a.numerator * b.denominator + a.denominator * b.numerator), (a.denominator * b.denominator));
    }
```

TestFraction.java(very incomplete, consists of just basic tests for now):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestFraction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the first fraction's numerator and denominator separated by spaces: ");
        Fraction myFraction1 = new Fraction(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Enter the second fraction's numerator and denominator separated by spaces: ");
        Fraction myFraction2 = new Fraction(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());

        Fraction.printFraction(myFraction1.getNumerator(), myFraction1.getDenominator());
        System.out.println();
        Fraction.printFraction(myFraction2.getNumerator(), myFraction2.getDenominator());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print(Fraction.gcd(myFraction1.getNumerator(), myFraction1.getDenominator()));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(Fraction.gcd(myFraction2.getNumerator(), myFraction2.getDenominator()));
        System.out.println();

        Fraction.reduceFraction(myFraction1.getNumerator(), myFraction1.getDenominator());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Fraction.addFraction(myFraction1, myFraction2));
    }
}
```

Comment: try to do test with JUnit https://junit.org/junit5/ it will be more efficient!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions:

- make your class immutable (i.e. no setters / mutators and the 2 variables should be final). There is really no great arguments for allowing a 'value' class like this to change and it will simplify things a lot because you never need to worry about things changing after the object is constructed. It is also consistent with all the `Number` classes in the Java api - none of them allow you to change value after construction.
- handle zero denominator in the constructor by throwing exception - then you never need to worry about that case anywhere else
- handle negative fractions in the constructor. Simplest way is to always end the constructor with the denominator positive. That way you never end up with weird looking fractions strings like "3/-4"
- add `Fraction.UNIT` and `Fraction.ZERO` constants
- add `equals` (and `hashCode`) methods - you want `new Fraction(1, 1).equals(new Fraction(1, 1))` to return `true` and currently it would return `false`
- also handle reduction to simplest form in the constructor if you want all fractions reduced to simplest form.
- if you want to handle fractions not in simplest form then make `reduce` a method in `Fraction`. There's no reason for this to be a public static
- have a `negate` method that just switches the sign of the numerator
- have an `inverse` method that just switches denominator and numerator
- then `substract` can just be a composition of `negate` and `add` and `divide` can be a composition of `inverse` and `multiply`
- use `toString` to convert to `String`

Final suggestion is to learn to use junit and (IMO) assertj and write custom assertions and a method for creating new fractions in your test calss. Then you end up with much more natural test cases such as:

```
assertThat(fraction(2, 4)).isEqualTo(fraction(1, 2));
assertThat(fraction(1, 7).negate()).isEqualTo(fraction(-1, 7));
assertThat(fraction(4, 16)).hasNumerator(1).hasDenominator(4);
assertThatExceptionOfType(ArithmeticException.class)
    .isThrownBy(() -> fraction(1, 0));
```

This will give failing tests MUCH easier to understand error messages.

Ideally you should have many of these types of tests showing that your algorithm works in all the weird edge cases it will need to handle.

Comment: I will definitely look into your suggestions. Although most of the stuff you're talking about is stuff I've never heard of, I want to improve my skills so I can handle more complex problems. And as for making the class immutable, I'm afraid I can't do that per the instructions from my professor. But thank you for all the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to System.out.print an object. 
To fix it you can in the fraction class write a toString() function [like here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_tostring.htm)

and print your result like now

```
public string toString(){
    return this.numerator+'/'+ this.denominator;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling that I would need to do this but I wasn't sure how to.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You're calling a println on `addFraction`, which is a method that returns an object of type `Fraction`.
When you call a println on a Java object, it returns the object's `toString()` method. By default, this method is "hidden" and will return the object's hash code (the weird number you're seeing).

Here are few options to fix this:

a) Override the `toString()` method.
Just add the following block of code inside the `Fraction` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "numerator=" + numerator + ", denominator=" + denominator + "]";
}
```

b) Print the properties of the object instead.
Replace your last println line with the following:

```
Fraction fraction = Fraction.addFraction(myFraction1, myFraction2);
System.out.println( String.format("numerator=%d, denominator=%d", fraction.getNumerator(), fraction.getDenominator()) );
```

Take some time to grasp the concepts explained by @sprinter, as it will help you write better code in the future. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is good to know. I have seen toString methods before while googling help but I wasn't sure if I needed one.